# Ouput of gdalinfo.exe --formats

Tags: gdal

I would like to get the output of the following command :

```
gdalinfo --formats > formats.txt
```

In Linux, it works

In Windows, it works but the output is not completed.

Do you know how to get the complete output in Windows ?

EDIT :
I know it's not complete because it finished in the middle of the line
End of my file :

```
GSC -raster- (rov): GSC Geogrid
FAST -raster- (rov): EOSAT FAST Format
BT -raster- (rw+v): VTP .bt (Binary Terrain) 1.3 Format
LA
```

I try different OS, windows 2016, 2019, 10 and differents versions of GDAL, the last one i try is 3.0.0.

EDIT 2 :
I run some test and found out the problem but don't know how to handle it.
So I took the gdal from here :
[Gdal with mapserver](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506152542/https://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1911-x64-gdal-3-0-0-mapserver-7-4-0.zip)

From here bin\gdal\apps I copy gdalinfo.exe and put in in bin.

I run `gdalinfo --formats > formats.txt` and it works

But after that I add a plugin ECW From [Here](https://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1911-x64-gdal-3-0-0-mapserver-7-4-0/gdal-300-1911-x64-ecw-33.msi)

I extract the msi, I copy paste the gdalplugins and libecwj2.dll to the previous bin folder

And now the commands is not completed. I don't know why.

Comment: Works for me with GDAL 3.1.0dev and GDAL 2.4.0.

Comment: Not completed how? Does the output end in the middle of a line? Or are there whole lines missing? How do you know? Does it look okay when not piped to a file?

Comment: I Edit my questions, the output end in the middle of a line and I try different OS and version of GDAL.

Comment: Works for me GDAL 2.4.0, windows 7.

Comment: The problem is that I add a plugin (ECW), before adding the plugin the command works as expected after I add it, it doesn't